# How to get the first number of a big number in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Okay so what I'm trying to do in AS3 is get the first number of a big number.

For example if I have a variable named TesterNum and it equals to 6:4204542
I'm trying to get the first number of the variable, which is 6.

I'm trying to create a code that says:

```
var TesterNum:Number = 6:4204542;
if(TheFirstNumberOfTesterNum == 6){
trace("Works");
}
```

What's the code to get the first number of a variable?

Comment: And you, what's the code that you have tried ? Did you tried [`string.charAt()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#charAt()) or [`string.substr()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#substr()) ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your variable is a String and not a Number (because of the colon which would cause your code in your question to throw a compiler error).

In that case, there are a few ways to do the same thing:

1. Use `parseInt` - which will grab the whole number prior to anything that is not a number, so in your case, anything before the colon.  This will be the easiest if your. first number can be more than one digit.

   ```
    var TesterNum = "6:4204542";
    if(parseInt(TesterNum) == 6) //true
   ```
2. Use `charAt`, which get's the character at the specified index, then convert that character to an integer.  This method is alright if you only need one digit ever.

   ```
   var TesterNum = "6:4204542";
   if(int(TesterNum.charAt(0)) == 6) //true
   ```
3. Use `substr`to get all characters before the colon, then convert that to a Number or integer.  This is exactly the same result as method #1.

   ```
   int(TesterNum.substr(0, TesterNum.indexOf(":"))) == 6
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use chatAt(); method like this:

```
var TesterNum:Number = 6:4204542;
var control:String = TesterNum.charAt(0);
trace(control);
//it give you 6
```